# jsoup select() method not found

Tags: java, netbeans, jsoup

I want to make a web parser in java. I'm using jsoup. But I got an error like this
[image]

[image]

how to fix it? is it because of my classpath?
[image]

also this are my imports
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(I).get(); 
Elements links = doc.select("div#content > p").first();
```

Comment: i think you have multiple import statement , so please check duplicate Element is imported or not.

Comment: you have imported wrong Document  class. remove javax.swing.text.Document  import.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the Document from Connection.

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url);
Document doc = con.get();
```

Comment: I got an error =  org.jsoup.nodes.Document cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.Document

Comment: use this import: import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;